# Can anyone tell me how to rotate UIStepper clockwise vertically which will get the plus on top and minus down?

Tags: ios, ipad

I have used UIStepper just besides a textBox in my app and have rotated it vertically as below:
[m_stepper1 setTransform:CGAffineTransformConcat(CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI_2), CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.4, 0.4))];
But that gives me plus sign below and minus sign on top. Can anyone help me out to rotate the stepper clockwise?

Comment: Did you try substituting `M_PI_2` with `-M_PI_2`?

Comment: oh ya. i had not tried that since i was very new to stepper. Thanx a lot.

Answer (score 1):

@Jugale : Thank you for the answer.

Just substitute M_PI_2 with -M_PI_2 and you will get the stepper rotated clockwise.

Answer (score 0):

```
let scale = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1, y: 0.8)
        sampleStepper.transform = scale.rotated(by: -(.pi/2))
```

Comment: It would be great if you'd not only just drop some code, but also give an explanation of what is going on in his and your code. It helps the question author and other users. It's good if it works, but knowing why is even more important in my opinion.